# Error Code: 21002 currency: Required parameter missing (CCAvenue) using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ccavenue

I have installed the plugin and set it up successfully, but when I tried to pay with this, it's showing error:

> "Error Code: 21002 Invalid Currency Parameter."

After code review I came to know that query string, the `currency` parameter getting changed to "`¤cy=INR`" as "`¤`" is getting executed as html special character.

This is query getting...

> merchant_id=123456789&order_id=xxxxxxxx&amount=1.00¤cy=INR&language=EN&billing_name=gfgh
>   ghfhgfgh&billing_address=abc&billing_city=abc

Comment: Hello, I'm also facing same issue. please let me know if this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As per the html entities, &curren; belongs to ¤, when you use &currency in the URL, it automatically gets converted to ¤cy. Even last semicolon (;) is not there in the &curren, it still creates ¤ html entity. 
Solution to this problem is

1. to either use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)
   `urlencode(merchant_id=123456789&order_id=xxxxxxxx&amount=1.00&currency=INR&language=EN&billing_name=gfghghfhgfgh&billing_address=abc&billing_city=abc)` or
2. to use html
       entity for & character like `amount=1.00&amp;currency=INR`

Comment: If I use urlencode than it wrongly encoded. and use &amp; then shows same error.

Comment: Found solution! keep request and cancel redirect url same. If your redirect url is same as ccavRequest than its again redirect to the same page with ¤cy=INR html content.